# MySql Join Issue When Join Two Tables

Tags: mysql

I have some doubt in MySQL joins

I have 2 tables for example TableA,TableB

TableA primary key is Foreign key of Table B

So I'm using inner join to get matched values but TableB have one column for row activate status so all active status is zero means I need to get that record or else I need to skip that record.

My query:.

```
Select * From TableA a inner join TableB b on a.id=b.aid where b.isActive=0;
```

The above query was return value if any one value is true

For example any one of is active row true. But I need to check all row is zero if it's all value zero means I need to return that so how I do that..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.* 
From TableA a 
where not exists(SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE a.id=b.aid AND b.isActive=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query change the filter as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a 
JOIN TableB b ON a.id=b.aid 
WHERE a.id NOT IN(SELECT aid FROM TableB WHERE isActive=1)
```